# How to create my own http context for a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, quartz-scheduler, httpcontext

I am using asp.net mvc 3 and quartz scheduler.

Currently I have this

1. A job gets created and executed.
2. Goes to a controller where I map domain to view models with automapper
3. Results go to controller where I want to use  [Action Mailer](https://bitbucket.org/swaj/actionmailer.net/overview)

I get an error

```
System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: httpContext
  Source=System.Web
  ParamName=httpContext
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.Routing.RequestContext..ctor(HttpContextBase httpContext, RouteData routeData)
       at ActionMailer.Net.MailerBase.Email(String viewName, Object model, String masterName)
       at EmailController.SendCalendarAppointmentNotifiation(CalendarAppointmentReminderVM vm) in EmailController.cs:line 73
       at RemindersController.CalendarAppointmentsReminders(List`1 taskReminders) in RemindersController.cs:line 54
       at QuartzJobs.AppointmentRemindersJob.Execute(JobExecutionContext context) in AppointmentRemindersJob.cs:line 39
       at Quartz.Core.JobRunShell.Run()
  InnerException:
```

// Job

```
public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
        {


                            // some code to do some checking and to get results above(not shown)
                            RemindersController remindersController = new RemindersController();
                            remindersController.CalendarAppointmentsReminders(calendarAppointmentReminders);

            }
```

// controller (to do mapping)\

```
   public void CalendarAppointmentsReminders(List<AppointmentReminder> appointments)
        {
           List<CalendarAppointmentReminderVM> vm = Mapper.Map<List<CalendarAppointment>, List<CalendarAppointmentReminderVM>>(appointments.Select(x => x.CalendarAppointment).ToList());
            Mapper.Map<List<AppointmentReminder>, List<CalendarAppointmentReminderVM>>(appointments, vm);


            foreach (var v in vm)
            {
                new EmailController().SendCalendarAppointmentNotifiation(v);
            }

        }
```

// mvc mailer

```
 public EmailResult SendCalendarAppointmentNotifiation(CalendarAppointmentReminderVM vm)
        {
            To.Add(vm.To);
            Subject = String.Format("Subject");
            return Email("SendCalendarAppointmentEmail", vm);
        }
```

Dies right on `return Email("SendCalendarAppointmentEmail", vm);` I want to use this as I am using it to send out all my other emails and I find it alot better way to send emails(easier to make them look nicer as you can use master pages and strongly typed views).

Comment: Have you set up your SMTP settings properly?

Comment: @ Brian Driscoll - Setup to go to a local folder and all my other ones work(ones that a user request a from and contacts my controller where I call up this email controller and send out emails...so the httpcontext is made for me on the first call to the controoler)

Comment: Was this problem solved? Please provide details. Thanks

Comment: I got the same problem with ActionMailer, it do not allow to send e-mail if HttpContext do not exists. That a huge limitation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Job execution of Quartz doesn't run in a HttpRequest. Also HttpContext.Current is NULL.
It seems that this asp.net mailer doesn't work without the asp.net request environment (hava a look at StackTrace)

checkout [Render a view as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string) (render view, put into mail and send..), but unfortunately in this post all samples works with the current ControllerContext/HttpContext too.

Comment: Müller - Yes HttpContext is null. I actually got the names mixed up I am using ActionMailer not asp.net mvc mailer. I think both of these email senders suffer from the same problem they need the HttpContext. I am lost on step one. What is that doing? So in my first controller I should put the step one code in?

Comment: i did this with mvc2, sending asp.net rendered partial views by email in a job. i will post you the code

Comment: how can I use it though if I need the httpContext?